# Tomcat can't connect to 8005 port

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, tomcat

I am setting up a web app environment to run Java apps.
The environment is supposed to be:

- AWS EC2 Ubuntu
- Java 8
- Tomcat 9

I launched an EC2 instance and installed java, then I followed this guide in order to set up Tomcat:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804

The problem now rises when `systemctl` tries to start/restart Tomcat service. Here is what I see when checking out systemctl logs:

```
Dec 19 13:35:25 ip-10-165-10-74 systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: Dec 19, 2018 1:35:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:8005] (base port [8005] and offset [0]). Tomcat may not be running.
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: Dec 19, 2018 1:35:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: SEVERE: Error stopping Catalina
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:513)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:403)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:497)
Dec 19 13:35:26 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal.
Dec 19 13:35:27 ip-10-165-10-74 shutdown.sh[1725]: Tomcat stopped.
```

As I understand the problem here is that Tomcat cannot connect to 8005 port in order to listen to shutdown commands.

However, I opened this port in EC2 Security Group console:
[image]

The other strange thing is that Tomcat starts okay when rebooting ec2 instance, but fails to restart throwing the exception like above.

What could be a problem here? How do I check that port 8005 is actually open?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: thanks, I posted this question on another site now. However, I cannot delete it from here. So, I guess, it is up to admins to do that.

Comment: Yeah, that's because there's an upvoted answer. Ping one of the mods and they can tend to it. You can contact a moderator by clicking the *flag* link. (You also get your points back once deleted).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows there is a Resource monitor in built to look into used ports.

You should be able to find it in:

`Start >> All Programs >> Accessories >> System Tools >> Resource Monitor`

All you have to do then is look for the 8005 for availability and its status,

If you are running on a Mac/Linux system then I would use netstat on a command promp to check that.

You can do `$netstat -a` too look into all sockets currently in use.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are on Ubuntu, type `netstat -tlp` in the term.

Explain:

`-t: tcp, -l: listening socket, -p: show pid and program name`